# Command line output on command line only install is ultra slow to print newlines

Tags: 16.04, command-line, printing

I've got one 16.04 server that behaves differently than my others where it prints newlines super slow.

For example, when the computer is starting and getting ready before asking me to login, the output it gives hangs about half a second between each line it prints which makes doing anything take extremely longer than it should be.

If I SSH into the server instead of using it directly it works normally, no slowness.

The GUI is disabled on this install, once it turns on it takes me to the command line login prompt, so this isn't related to the Ubuntu Terminal app.

I have a video of the behavior as well, which should hopefully clear up my description of what's happening https://youtu.be/cPYm5G71O-0

---

stty -a

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 67; columns 240; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Comment: Do you have custom prompt settings? What is the output of `echo $PS1`?

Comment: @Jos `%{$fg[red]%}%m%{$reset_color%}:%{$fg[green]%}%c%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info) %(!.#.$)`

Comment: Probably also worth noting that this behaves exactly the same in ZSH as the default terminal, and this is almost a fresh install, it mainly just houses files, so new has been installed to it

Comment: You may look into your terminal settings. What is the output of `stty -a`? Please edit your question and paste the output .

Comment: @Jos the question has been updated

Comment: My settings (Ubuntu Server 18.04) are identical except for `hupcl`, `brkint` and `imaxbel`. I changed those to your settings but the result was the same.

Comment: @Jos Damn, I wonder if it's a hardware thing somehow then. This server is my only one with a different branded motherboard than the others (Super Micro, the others are consumer Gigabyte boards)

Comment: Have you tried a different monitor?

Comment: Yes, it's not the monitor, if I start the GUI up it runs just fine, it's just in command line mode it behaves differently

Comment: What happens when you switch to a different tty session? (CTRL+ALT+Fn)

Comment: @JaradDowning Sorry, these servers were having other issues so we eventually replaced the boards with a different model (consumer board) and all the issues just went away